# Accessing Data of a FormArray of FormGroup

Tags: angular, formarray, formgroups

so I've got this FormBuilder setup:

```
surveyForm: FormGroup;
ngOnInit(): void {
     this.surveyForm = this.formBuilder.group({
       'surveyTitle': new FormControl(null),
       'surveyDescription': new FormControl(null),
       'questionsDetail': this.formBuilder.array([
         this.formBuilder.group({
           'questionType': new FormControl('mcq'),
           'question': new FormControl(null),
           'choices': this.formBuilder.array([])
         })
       ])
     });
    };
```

and i tried to access the control of choices using this code:

```
 onAddChoice()
  {
    const control = new FormControl(null, Validators.required);
    this.surveyForm.controls.questionsDetail.control.push(control);
  }
```

and i get this error

> quote Property 'control' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

If someone can help me, that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `controls` not `control`

```
this.surveyForm.controls.questionsDetail.controls.push(control);
```

And I'd recommend you to use `addControl` method of formArray control, it is more verbose.

```
(this.surveyForm.get('questionsDetail') as FormArray).addControl(control);
```